# iSDK - Can't call function sendEmail (undefined function)

Tags: php, api, infusionsoft

I am using this API "https://github.com/infusionsoft/PHP-iSDK".
I am calling it in a simple php file but I am having a error, I am new to php any body with some easy solution, here is my code.

```
<?php
  echo "Hello World! <br/>";
  include_once('iSDK/src/isdk.php');
  $myApp = new iSDK;

  if($myApp->cfgCon("connectionName")) {
      echo "Connected...";
  } else {
      echo "Not Connected...";
  }

  sendEmail('conList','fromAddress','toAddress', 'ccAddresses', 'bccAddresses', 'contentType', 'subject', 'htmlBody', 'txtBody');
?>
```

This code below give this error :

```
Call to undefined function sendEmail() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\email.php on line 16
```

Comment: check spelling of include_once

Comment: that is fine, that I just missed while putting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the only error in this code?

It looks like php can't find the function within iSDK.
The line `nclude_once'iSDK/src/isdk.php';` should be `include_once('iSDK/src/isdk.php');` and you should check, if the relative path is correct.

The first character in the next line is also missing: `myApp = new iSDK;` should be `$myApp = new iSDK();`

Second guess is to write `$myApp->sendEmail(` instead of `sendEmail(`

Comment: did you add the brackets to `new iSDK`

Comment: I added the brackets.

Comment: Try adding `$myApp->` before `sendEmail(`